# Sobel Edge Detection, edge orientation

Tags: computer-vision

I've implemented a Sobel Edge Detector and had some questions about computing edge orientations.

I'm using this function to compute edge intensities after having done the sobel kernel convolution.

Gxy = sqrt( pow(Gx, 2) + pow(Gy,2) )

Where Gx is sum of the convolution for the sobel kernel in the X direction and Gy is sum of the convolution for the sobel kernel in the Y direction. (note the sobel kernel in the X and Y direction are different kernels)

Y kernel:

- 1  2  1
- 0  0  0
- -1 -2 -1

X kernel:

- -1 0 1
- -2 0 2
- -1 0 1

when I try to compute the edge orientation (theta is in degrees), I'm using the following rules:

- if Gy == 0 and Gx == 0, then theta = 0
- if Gy != 0 and Gx == 0, then theta = 90
- otherwise, theta = (arctan( Gy / Gx ) * 180) / PI

all my documentation is telling me the angles should be > 0 and < 360 and I continue to get edges with negative value orientations. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly when computing theta or my convolution? Or should i just add 360 or 180 to negative theta values?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question precisely because you haven't mentioned exactly how you calculate the arctan function.

For example, if you're using the [standard library's atan function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan/), then negative angles are to be expected.

Furthermore, you'll notice that `atan` with a single argument can only ever return values in the first and fourth quadrants (because, for example, `tan 45 == tan 225` when using degrees).

If you really want an angle in one of the four quadrants (you should really ask yourself if this matters for your application), then have a look at [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/).

Comment: from the documentation i've been reviewing, (http://www.uweb.ucsb.edu/~shahnam/AfED.doc), i'm using the summed value of the sobel kernel for the Y direction (the Gy in my sample) and the summed value of the sobel kernel for the X direction (the Gx in my sample). I've seen some other places that recommend arctan2(Gy, Gx) to compute these values and I'm also getting negative angles. @misha, thanks for the assistance on the quadrant results, totally on point! for my application, quadrangle detection, 4 quadrants would probably work best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCV, C++ you could do the following:

```
    Mat gray = some grayscale image;
```

Calculate edge gradients in x/y axis'

```
    Mat dx(gray.rows, gray.cols, CV_16SC1);
    Mat dy(gray.rows, gray.cols, CV_16SC1);
    int aperture_size=3;
    Sobel(gray, dx, CV_32FC1, 1, 0, aperture_size, 1, 0, BORDER_REPLICATE);
    Sobel(gray, dy, CV_32FC1, 0, 1, aperture_size, 1, 0, BORDER_REPLICATE);
```

Calculate the angle and magnitude using OpenCV's [cartToPolar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#carttopolar)

```
    Mat Mag(gray.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat Angle(gray.size(), CV_32FC1);
    cartToPolar(dx, dy, Mag, Angle, true);
```